# Spring mvc project not running

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i have formatted my laptop .but now when i am running my previous project based on spring MVC  its not running .i am getting 404 error.` and in stacktrace i am getting error of unsatisfied dependency.
I have used spring MVC and hibernate and jdk8.
May be i am missing some configuration  but dont know what it is .i have already set the path of maven and jdk in environment variable.
here is the screenshot of error i am getting.[here is the screenshot of error i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6iFD.png)

Comment: Error showing that database is not created properly.

Comment: here i am using h2 database and i have already added the jdbc url ,username and password in my dbconfig file

Comment: Was it working before you formatted your laptop cz it seems to be having issue creating bean object `cartController` , If you're using @autowire annotation to create bean, consider checking annotation `@Service` or `@Component`  & '@Repository` in your **CartController** and **CartDao** classes.

Comment: yes it was working before formatting..and its also running properly on my friend's system

Comment: Is it a Maven project?

Comment: You could try to clean Tomcat work directory and remove and then add again your project

Comment: yes it is a maven project